# if statement within namespace gives error

Tags: c++, if-statement, namespaces

I have the following piece of C++ code which compiles without problem:

```
namespace namespace_top_of_FDD{
    int int_systemReturn=system("pause | echo scope: namespace_top_of_FDD");
    FDD*FDD_Ptr_Object=NULL;
    //if(true){}    
}
```

But when I add `if` statement, like the following, I get the following error massages, I'm wondering why.

```
namespace namespace_top_of_FDD{
    int int_systemReturn=system("pause | echo scope: namespace_top_of_FDD");
    FDD*FDD_Ptr_Object=NULL;
    if(true){}  
}
```

Error messages (when I use `if` statement):

```
 1>.\FDD.cpp(6) : error C2059: syntax error : 'if'
 1>.\FDD.cpp(6) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
 1>.\FDD.cpp(6) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Comment: Statements can appear only within function definitions.

Comment: Thanks, is there any standard method to get around this issue.

Comment: Put the statement inside a function definition. I don't know what you're getting to do.

Comment: Thanks, I can define a dummy function to do so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code in namespaces may contain only declarations and/or definitions (which in turn are declarations). You may not place executable statements similar to the if statement.

Comment: Is there any solution If I need to use "if" statement within namespace?

Comment: @user3853917  Maybe you mean preprocessor directive #if?

Comment: maybe I can replace it with directive #if

Comment: you can move that code to constructor of a class, and create a class instance in namespace.

Comment: Good option. I can try it.